# Bootstrap clearing html selector (background image)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just starting to understand enough HTML / CSS to drive myself crazy trying to implement new things.

I'm trying to create a landing page with a full width / height background image that resizes with the viewport. That's an easy enough proposition if you're not using any css framework but I'm trying to build bootstrap into the page.

With bootstrap any content that I add below the body selector clears my background image as if it were part of the normal box model. If I remove bootstrap the page functions as expected and overlays the content on top of the background image. I'm guessing something in bootstrap is clearing all page elements but I haven't been able to find it.

The code I'm using to apply the background image is:

```
html {
background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
z-index: -999;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to put the bg image on the root element?  If not, Pier-Luc's answer works.

Comment: I actually tried Pier's solution quickly after I posted the question and it worked. It just seems a bit odd that you can't have root elements applying styles.

Comment: bootstrap sets a margin on body with a value of 0.  Any top margin value > zero addresses the original question.   So if you wanted to use that declaration on the root element, you could also add something like "body {margin-top:1px}" and it should work.  Don't know if that is feasible for your layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an (indirect) [example](http://mode87.com/untame/demo/carousel/thumbnails.html) of a fullscreen background image using Twitter Bootstrap in this [blog post](http://untame.net/2013/04/twitter-bootstrap-carousel/).

The gist of it being:

```
body {
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Pier.

Comment: I don't pretend to know Bootstrap exceedingly well, but it probably has to do with the css reset they are using. P.S. don't forget to accept an answer when you get one that works!